# Android notification on wearable not visible enough

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, wear-os

It is about a notification on a wearable. I receive the notification on the watch, but the watch doesn't vibrate and only when I swipe up on the watch I see the notification. Like this it is pretty useless. The phone vibrates and shows the notification in the header. I want that on the watch the notification is either shown directly on the watch or that the watch vibrates. Or even both.

I am using the standard example code you find on many pages:

```
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender =  new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Hello Android Wear")
                    .setContentText("First Wearable notification.")
                    .extend(wearableExtender).setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your wear device is muted. Do you see smth similar to the first bell icon?

Swipe down to unmute the watch.

[image]